# Python 3 - Addition two float number with two decimals resulting in 12 decimals (or repeating decimal)

Tags: python, floating-point, numbers, rounding

**Windows 10**
**Python 3.11.3**
**Visual Studio Code**

I have a quite basic Python script, which loads an excel table into a pandas table, then summarize numbers based on another column and writes them into a list.

The numbers are always has a maximum of 2 decimals in the excel sheet (double checked, not hidden or anything). It has two decimals in the pandas. It even has two decimals in the variables before addition.
Then after the addition - boom - it is now has infinite repeating decimals.

The addition code looks like this:
`final_datas[line][8] += osszeg`

So simple.
When I print out the values of the variables to the console, before the addition, it is like this:

`11601.3 3480.39`

After the addition:

`15081.689999999999`

I don't understand why.

I have tried rounding the final number in multiple ways:

`round(final_datas[line][8], 2)`

`float("{:.2f}".format(final_datas[line][8]))`

Nothing worked :( Has anyone a sole idea what could possibly be the problem?

Comment: `print(f"{11601.3 + 3480.39:.2f}")` and/or `print("{0:.2f}".format(11601.3 + 3480.39))` should work for you. Note you are missing the `0` in your format string.